# How to notifiy app if someone turns of NFC via the quick settings menu?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm trying to create an app that reads an NFC chip and I was testing some of the edge cases. If NFC is disabled it shows an error message where you can enable it. The Problem now is that if you enable it and open the quick settings menu afterward to disable the NFC again my app doesn't recognize that change. Is there any way to get notified of this action?
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via Broadcastreceiver?

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: And how do you initialize the broadcast receiver? Do you put your action into the `onReceive()` Method?

Comment: Yes, you write your code in the onReceive() method. To initialize the broadcastreceiver, you do it like any other broadcastreceiver:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html